# Since which version does busybox ash built with ASH_BASH_COMPAT include array support?

Tags: array, busybox

[March 12th, 2009 Denys Vlasenko wrote](http://busybox.busybox.narkive.com/2Cpm3iNe/bash-like-arrays-with-busybox-ash#post5):

> Plans to implement it — *BASH like array support* — eventually for
>   `ASH_BASH_COMPAT`, yes. Need to have enough free time for that.
>   (volunteers much welcomed)

Since which `busybox` version does its `ash` compiled with `ASH_BASH_COMPAT` enabled
 include BASH like array support?

Comment: *Does* it support arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't.

I just pulled the latest version at https://git.busybox.net/busybox/ and built it with `ASH_BASH_COMPAT` enabled. (It's enabled by default; see `shell/Config.in`).

```
$ bash -c 'a=(zero one two) ; echo ${a[2]}'
two
$ ./busybox ash -c 'a=(zero one two) ; echo ${a[2]}'
ash: syntax error: unexpected "("
$
```

The latest update was 2017-12-26 20:19.